# Window could not start the tomcat 7 on Local Computer

Tags: tomcat

Window could not start the tomcat 7 on Local Computer.For more information, review the System Events Logs.If this is a non-Microsoft service,contact service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 0.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem

Comment: And the logs say... ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

- Open tomcat7w.exe at your *%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin* directory (e.g. *C:\Tomcat\Tomcat7\bin*).
- Go to the "Startup" and "Shutdown" tabs.
- Change the "Mode" field from "JVM" to "Java".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old ticket, but still sharing my suggestion with anyone who faces this issue.

1. Click Start → Run, type services.msc and then click OK.
2. Locate the Apache Tomcat service, and then verify that Running is listed in the Status column. If it is not running, try to start the service manually by selecting it and clicking Start.

If the error persists, follow these instructions to resolve your issue:

1. Navigate to your %TOMCAT_HOME%\bin directory (for example, C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat\Tomcat7\bin) and double-click tomcat7w.exe.
2. Click the Java tab, select the check box next to Use default and then click OK.
3. Start the Apache Tomcat service. The service should start without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and Tomcat 7 won't start after many attemps and forums search nothing could solve my problem, so I checked the `stdout` log file under logs folder of Tomcat 7 I found an error telling:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

When I checked Tomcat Configure(Tomcat7w under the bin folder of Tomcat) I found that I set Initial memory pool bigger than maximum memory pool by error, so I set them to the same value and Tomcat started well.